# Using oauth to authenticate and authorize angular and .Net core application

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, okta

I have a an an angular application with .Net core back end. I am trying to implement SSO using OpenIdConnect (Okta as a an IDP).

What is the best approach to do this? do I authenticate from the angular app using angular-oauth2-oidc?
or do I do it on the backend using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect?

Where should be my starting point? I want to also make sure that a an authenticated or an authorized user is able to call the Api endpoint from the browser or Swagger.

To be more generic in an application that has a UI and a backend how does SSO work? shiould the backend code handles the login process?

thanks

Comment: The answer depends on whether you plan to host your frontend and backend applications on the same domain and port. If you do, then you can handle all the authentication in your backend. If you want to deploy them on separate servers, then you should set up your backend as a resource server that validates JWTs and configure login on your frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement authentication in your angular application . Since Oktais your authentication/SSO service , the general process is user will be redirect to Okta's login page to sign in , after user enter credential and the Okta validates the credential , user will redirect back to your angular application with code(if using Authorization code flow +PKCE) , your application will send request to Okta service with code for acquiring ID token and access token , access token could be used to access your protected web apis .

For angular application , you can use [Okta Angular SDK](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/okta-angular) or [Okta Auth JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js)(The Auth SDK is a lower level SDK than the Okta Angular SDK) . You can refer to below article for tutorial & code sample :

https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/angular/nodejs/generic

Here is another article which provide detail steps with asp.net core web api as backend :

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/26/build-crud-app-aspnetcore-angular

PKCE Flow overview :

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-auth-code-pkce/overview/

Comment: Thank you- So that means I only need to Create one SPA in OKTA and use the token that the Front end generated to authenticate by back end services? I don't need to create web application in OKTA for the back end?

Comment: You need to create app for backend app , that is protected resource by OKTA , your front end app should grant permission to access your backend app in OKTA.

Comment: I have authentication working but Authorization is the problem. My Okta application authenticates just fine and the web api works with the Okta auth token. But, roles is the big problem. I should be able to get groups from Okta as roles and then decorate my web api methods with [Authorize(Roels="admin")] . Also, I would need roles to show/hide route/links in Angular after SSO using Okta. It seems Okta can only deal with Roles from MVC.